# Issue with Keras model running with TensorFlow for Android

Tags: android, tensorflow, keras

I try to train model with Keras and run in on android.

My model (with .pb extension) was correctly loaded and parsed, after it I called this:

```
tensorFlowInferenceInterface.run(outputNames, true);
```

And after it I has this issue:

```
E/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Failed to run TensorFlow inference with inputs:[main_input], outputs:[action_sm/Relu]
E/TensorflowAndroid: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'NotEqual' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:
                   <no registered kernels>

                     [[Node: NotEqual = NotEqual[T=DT_FLOAT](action_sm_sample_weights, NotEqual/y)]]
```

I tried to use the latest version of library (1.3.1-alpha), but it wasn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This code helps me to save model, that works on Android:

```
from keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util

sess = K.get_session()
K.set_learning_phase(0)
constant_graph = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, 
    sess.graph.as_graph_def(), outputs)

tf.train.write_graph(constant_graph, out_dir, "model.pb", False)
```